# Can I left or right justify my webpage that uses the 960 CSS framework?

Tags: css, 960.gs

I just started playing around with the 960 CSS framework and found that it centers my page in the browser.  How can I change this so that the page is aligned to the left side of the browser window?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would need to see your specific CSS stylesheet for the 960, but whatever your container div is called -- usually

```
<div id="container">
```

or something similar. In the CSS, you can accordingly remove this one-line setting:

```
#container { margin: 0 auto; }
```

That should align your 960 grid to the left and I see no reason why that would be a fundamental problem for the grid or for valid CSS.